# How to install new version in android

Tags: android

I published my app in version 1. Now I builded Version 2. But When I install new Version doesn't Install. I should uninstall privious version! I should say I signed both versions with 1 key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check your key and your building procedure to see if it it's building new apks and push it to your device.
I use Intellij IDEA to develop and test my project. If I signed a newer apk with different key, it will ask me to uninstall the previous one by clicking YES.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You are doing one of two things, either you are using a different key, or you used the debug key for the first build, and production key for the second build, or vice versa.